# Only last values in array are being posted to mysql database need all values posted

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently using codeigniter to grab data from a MySQL table and displaying it on screen. The data is being displayed in an html form so when the user logs into my website the data from the database is already being displayed.

What I would like to happen is if the user changes some of the data in the fields and then pushes the upload button the data should be pushed back to the database and if they refresh the screen their changes should show.

At the moment when I go to push the changes only the last values in the array are being sent. How can I have all of the values in my array sent to the MySQL database. Below is my code for the view, controller, and model. Any help is greatly appreciated!

View

```
<?php 
    $i=0;
    echo form_open('site/push_data');
            foreach($query as $row): 
                echo form_input('lab['.$i.'][priority]', $row->priority);
                echo form_input('lab['.$i.'][item]', $row->item);
                echo form_input('lab['.$i.'][equipment]', $row->equipment);
                echo form_input('lab['.$i.'][post]', $row->post);
                echo form_input('lab['.$i.'][item_type]', $row->item_type); 
                $i++;
             endforeach;
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Push');
    echo form_close();
?>
<h4><?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?></h4>
```

Controller

```
function push_data()
{
    $this->load->model('display_lab_data');
    $this->display_lab_data->writeToDB($this->input->post('lab'));
}
```

Model

```
function writeToDB($data) 
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
        {
            print_r($_POST['lab'][$i]);
            $this->db->update_batch('lab_priority_list', $_POST['lab'][$i]);
        }
        /*print_r($_POST['lab']);
        foreach($_POST['lab'] as $Value)
        {
            $this->db->update('lab_priority_list', $Value);
        }*/
    }
```

Current content of my array

```
Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 ) Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 ) Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 ) Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 ) Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 ) Array ( [priority] => 600 [item] => 78920 [equipment] => machine 53 [post] => blidoolpoop [item_type] => 1 )
```

Comment: try print_r($_POST) at start of your writeToDB function and see if every post is coming which you are looping through @Rizwan Chaudry

Comment: Hi mahida, thank you for the reply. I have done a print_r($POST) and all values are being printed. Could it be something with the way I am creating my array? Or maybe the way I'm itterating through it?

Comment: In update_batch there is error, where are you passing the id for update? @RizwanChaudry

Comment: Ah I apologize the code I have working currently is using just the update method. I attempted to try update_batch to see if that would work but I do not know what $id I should be passing to the method.

Comment: Is update_batch the appropriate function to use here?

Comment: What is the primary key in your `lab_priority_list` table?

Comment: The primary key is supposed to be the priority but I have not set it to be. Going to do that now. (UPDATE) I have set the priority column to be the primary key.

Comment: Pass the priority value coming from post as id to update the record @RizwanChaudry

Comment: So now that I have set up the primary key I have attempted to push only two rows of data one with a priority number of 1 and another with a priority number of 2. When I attempt this I get an sql error stating that there is duplicate data being posted. Could this now be a matter of trying to only push the changes made rather than the entire row of data?

Comment: @mahida I apologize but how should I specify the id? I have attempted to try:$this->db->update_batch('lab_priority_list', $_POST['lab'][$i], 'priority') but that still causes an error stating I need to specify an id.

Comment: You habe to look into update_batch function in your model what it accept as arguments @Rizwan

Comment: I have looked at the update_batch function in the codeingiter documentation and I have tried passing the required parameters which are : 
(•$table (string) – Table name
•$set (array) – Field name, or an associative array of field/value pairs
•$value (string) – Field value, if $set is a single field
•$batch_size (int) – Count of conditions to group in a single query)                                                                                                             but I still receive the same error of not specifying the proper index. I am lost as to what exactly that should be.